# Limites do Google Maps API (server-side)

Tags: php, google-maps, libcurl, google-maps-api-3

Estou projetando um sistema em PHP, que fará acesso ao Geocoding do Google Maps API via URL (cURL).

Esse sistema será vendido para clientes diferentes. Todos os sistemas vendidos ficarão no mesmo servidor.

Cada sistema/cliente terá sua própria Chave (API Key).

PROBLEMA:

O Google Maps API tem limite de acesso por Chave.
O Google Maps API será acessado por várias Chaves diferentes, porém, vindas de um mesmo IP.
Por conta disso, o Google poderá entender uma fraude? Pois aparentemente, parece que alguém está usando várias Chaves em um único aplicativo, tentando burlar o limite de acessos?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que essa questão seja mais jurídica do que de programação. Uma vez que apenas lendo os termos irá encontrar essa informação.

Nem sei se deveria responder e nem sei se as informações aqui vão estar corretas, o ideal seria contactar Google ou ler com mais calma todos os termos do Google Maps. Eu apenas procurei por alguns tópicos que acreditei que mencionaram sobre uso de chaves.

---

> "O Google Maps API tem limite de acesso por Chave. O Google Maps API será acessado por várias Chaves diferentes"

Se seu intuito é justamente "bypassar" o limite, ou seja burlar o limite usando várias chaves isso é claramente uma violação dos termos do Google:

> Quota limits are enforced on a unique project basis, and you may not take any action to circumvent quota limits. For example, you may not create multiple projects to compound and exceed quota limits.

[Você pode contratar limites maiores e não ter essa preocupação.](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/) O limite do Google é por aplicação e não por cliente, portanto você é uma aplicação só e não faz sentido algum você ter mais de uma chave.

Além disso nem todos os recursos do Google Maps precisam de chaves, [como mencionado aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem).

Isso está claramente definido aqui:

> No use beyond transaction limits and usage policies. If your Maps API
> Implementation generates a high volume of transactions, Google
> reserves the right to set transaction limits, as described in the Maps
> APIs Documentation here. Google also reserves the right to set other
> usage policies in the Documentation from time to time. If you want to
> engage in use outside these transaction limits or usage policies, you
> can purchase more usage capacity through the Maps API Standard pricing
> plan, or you can contact the Google Maps sales team for licensing
> options to address your needs. Google may decline your request, or
> condition acceptance on your agreement to additional terms and/or
> charges for that use.

Se cada chave tem 2500 chamadas e você possui 10 chaves automaticamente você é capaz de fazer mais chamadas do que o limite, afinal agora poderá fazer 25000 somados todas as chaves.

---

O Google possui restrições para uso comerciais como mencionado:

> Entretanto, nem todos os usos comerciais são permitidos. Por exemplo,
> se seu site atende a qualquer um dos critérios a seguir, você deve
> comprar a licença apropriada da Google Maps APIs Premium Plan:
>
> Seu site é disponibilizado apenas para clientes pagantes. Seu site só
> pode ser acessado em sua empresa ou pela sua intranet. Seu aplicativo
> está relacionado a expedição empresarial, gerenciamento de frota,
> rastreamento de ativos de negócios ou atividades semelhantes.

Logo se este for o caso você terá que migrar para o "Premium Plan", mencionado acima, o que já não fará sentido em ter várias chaves.

Isso também é definido em:

> No asset-tracking unless you have purchased the applicable enterprise
> license. Unless you have purchased an applicable Premium Plan or Maps
> APIs for Work license that expressly permits you to do so, you will
> not use the Service or Content for commercial asset-tracking or in
> Maps API Implementations whose primary purpose is to assess vehicle
> insurance risks:
>
> Commercial asset-tracking includes dispatch, fleet
> management, and Maps API Implementations that track your (or your end
> users’) assets (for example, private or commercial transportation
> applications, including taxi and vehicle-for-hire applications).
>
> Non-commercial asset-tracking implementations include applications
> used for a non-commercial purpose (for example, a free, publicly
> accessible Maps API Implementation that displays real-time public
> transit or other transportation status information or that allows end
> users to share real-time location with others).

---

---

Fontes:

1. https://developers.google.com/maps/faq
2. https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_4

Comment: Não, não tenho o intuito de burlar o limite, pelo contrário, minha duvida é para me precaver de problemas futuro. Mas fiquei chateado do Google não permitir colocar diferentes sistemas em um mesmo servidor, pois por usarem o mesmo IP, poderá surgir problemas.

Comment: Mas qual seria o problema de utilizar uma única chave, ao invés de usar várias chaves distintas?

Comment: Pelo fato de que cada sistema de cliente é independente, porém estarão no mesmo servidor de hospedagem. Seria injusto que por culpa de 1 cliente que usou muito o sistema, os demais também sejam bloqueados para usar o mapa de seu respectivo sistema

Comment: O correto é cada cliente ter sua chave.